# Remove Link from item in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, anchor

Pretty new to ASP.NET and trying to figure out how to have the code just echo the information it fetched.

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <% foreach (var cat in Model.Categories.Where(x=>x.ParentId==null).OrderBy(x=>x.DisplayOrder).ThenBy(x=>x.CategoryName)) { %>
        <li style="height: auto; min-height:30px;">
            <%= Html.ActionLink(cat.CategoryName, "Index", "Products", new { id=cat.UniqueName, area="" }, null)%>

            <%if(cat.SubCategories.Count>0) {%>
                <ul class="sub-menu" style="font-size:.8em; padding-left:20px;">
                    <% foreach (var c in cat.SubCategories) { %>
                        <li><%= Html.ActionLink(c.CategoryName, "Index", "Products", new { id=c.UniqueName, area="" }, null)%></li>
                    <% } %>
                </ul>
            <%}%>
        </li>
    <%} %>
</ul>
```

Currently I know it has to do with `<%= Html.ActionLink(cat.CategoryName, "Index", "Products", new { id=cat.UniqueName, area="" }, null)%>` that line but not sure how to make it pass the information. Might be a stupid question but Google definitely did not help when searching for this answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more descriptive, what are you trying to include? Right now the Html.Action link will create a link with the Category Name as the text going to the Products controller Index action. It will pass Unique Name as the ID. Also, I suggest tagging your code for asp.net mvc

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, what I am asking is to remove the link but still have the information passed. Example: 

<a href="#">LINK HERE</a>

I just want the word "Link Here" without the link.

Comment: <a href="#">@c.CategoryName</a>

Comment: Im sorry really confused, I am learning this as I go. So if I wanted to post the content without the link i could replace `<%= Html.ActionLink(cat.CategoryName, "Index", "Products", new { id=cat.UniqueName, area="" }, null)%>` with just `@c.CategoryName` ?

Comment: thanks. At first i was confused to why it wasn't working but it was <%= cat.CategoryName %>.

Comment: It was my mistake, @ is Razor syntax and is the equilivant of <%: which is Response.Write with HTML Encode. <%= is Response.Write with no HTML encoding (which is the same as @Html.Raw in Razor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brief overview of some of the commands:

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink(cat.CategoryName, "Index", "Products", new { id=cat.UniqueName, area="" }, null)%>
```

Will create:

```
 <a href="products/index/{UniqueName}">{CategoryName}</a>
```

Which can also be constructued as:

```
 <a href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Products", new { id=cat.UniqueName, area="" })%>"><%: cat.CategoryName%></a>
```

Which will also create:

```
 <a href="products/index/{UniqueName}">{CategoryName}</a>
```

So, you can output just the name or ID using:

```
 <%: cat.CategoryName %>
```

OR

```
 <%= cat.CategoryName %>
```

<%= is "Response.Write" and "<%:" Is Response.Write with HTML Encode